# Windows service stopped while restarting server?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have created more than 5 windows service in server,It was running on weekly basis by automatically,But when I restart the server all services were stopped.

How to fix it?

Comment: What is start type of those services? If it is "automatic", then you should check Windows application log.

Comment: Check the [event viewer](http://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/event-viewer-troubleshoot-windows-services/) for errors from your services

Answer (score 0):

Make the Startup type of your service to automatic.

Comment: Yes, already  I put automatic, but while restarting server all service was stopped and again I will start service once,